# Ionic 4: If i clear the app build(IOS/Android) on devices it's asking me again to re-login

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-storage

Ionic 4: If I clear the app build(IOS/Android) on devices it's asking me again to re-login and deletes the session but if I Login on the web browser the session is active and I can able to see the auth token and login credentials. I used ionic storage source. For mobile devices what to do, needs suggestions using SQLite but I'm confused about how to save and make user details to skip the login page. Waiting for your suggestions and code examples using the Rest-API to keep the login session active on mobile devices. The motive of this app is to work only on mobile devices, not on the web(PWA).

Comment: Can you please show the code to store data.

Comment: If you clear the app data there is no way app is stop running delete all of the storage with database. So you need to save your login credentials in the ionic storage then access at the app was started if you found data then user login either redirect to the login page